# How to using data from console to make ternery in next js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, console.log

I want to use data from console but i dont know how to do it.

my code :

```js
var Success = true;
var url = new URL(`https://${link}`);
var req = https.get(
    url,
    function (res) {
        res.statusCode === 200 ? (Success = true) : (Success = false);
        console.log(res);
    }
};
```

The problem is that Success variable can't be used in in function(res).
I want to use that in here so i would know if the url can be access or not.

```js
<td
    className={`px-4 py-3 ${
        Success
            ? `text-emerald-500`
            : `text-red-500`
    }  text-center`}
>
    {Success ? Success : Failed}
</td>
```

[image]

Comment: can't you use `useState` instead of `var`?

Comment: it also can't be use

Comment: Can you post the full component's code?